# ESP32 - 5V output to operate a Relay

Tags: esp32, power-sources

I'm playing around with a new ESP32 flashed with Micropython [from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/WEMOS-Wifi-bluetooth-Board-LOLIN32-Lite-Based-ESP32-CH340-MicroPython-4MB-FLASH/173042752651?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) in order to replace a Rpi Zero W. Am I missing the 5v output? I need it to operate a Relay.

Can a 5vDC Relay be operated as needed to operate using 3.3vDC?

Comment: there is no 5v anything on the esp32, it's a 3.3v device. You can use a mosfet to drive your 5v relay's signal line

Comment: Given your uptime requirements, you may want to ask this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions
In particular, you may need to ask about a solid state relay triggered by 3.3V. Mechanical relays tend to die after fewer cycles.

Comment: I've moved the discussion about the merits of an RPi in this situation [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80482/discussion-on-question-by-guy-d-esp32-5v-output-to-operate-a-relay) so that you can discuss it in more detail without getting too far off-topic here.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/213051/130336) on our sister site, by any chance?  If not, give it a check - it might help out a bit.